# Define a class outside the class in which it is declared C++

Tags: c++, syntax

I often declares classes in other classes. Code:

```
class Human {
public:

  class Hand;
  class Foot;

  // ...
};

class Human::Hand {
public:
  // ...
};

class Human::Foot {
public:
  // ...
};
```

But if Human has Hand object(not pointer), then I get

> error C2079: 'Human::hand' uses undefined class 'Human::Hand'

How can I solve it?
Or maybe you know a better way to classify classes?

Comment: You cannot without fully defining the nested class in that case. Since the compiler needs to know the size of that object when generating code. Now, if you were using a pointer or reference, then it would behave like a forward definition and you can move the nested classes outside.

Comment: @TanveerBadar ↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: Yes, as @TanveerBadar mentioned, you cannot use a [Incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) here.